# katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications not working

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

My Controller action for button ng-click event
whenever i click on the button nothing happens
cordova.plugins.notification.local
is not working at all i m not getting any notifications on my mobile
Please help

```
 $scope.notify = function() {
    console.log("com");
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
       // cordova.plugins.notification.local is now available
        cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
            id:021,
            title: "New Message",
            message: "Hi, are you ready? We are waiting.",
            icon: "http://asset2.cfcdn.com/cfassets/images/logo-tab.png"
        });

    }, false);
};
```

Comment: you are still unable to get Local Notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML below should work for you:

```html
<button ng-click="notify()">notify</button>
```

Otherwise you probably haven't installed the plugin properly. Do you get any errors in your console?